# Laravel Auth::attempt keeps returning false

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I have made a login script, which i've used several times before, and it has always worked perfectly fine, as did it in this project until yesterday.

The only real change I've made to the project in general was update something because i believe it was migrations who complained that it was more than 30 days old or something. i just followed instructions.

Now the script itself however, i haven't touched at all.
I've come to the conclusion that it is the `Auth::attempt` that fails, because I know the script recieves the information and connects to the database, and i know that the information passed to the database is correct. still it returns false.

My password column in the database is a varchar(100) and has as i mentioned earlier worked just fine a couple of days ago. Read on other threads that it must be at least 60. i just can't find the error and any help would be greatly appriciated.

```
public function doLogin()
{
    $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6|max:16',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6|max:16'
        );


    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules); 

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        if(Request::ajax()){
            return Response::json($validator->getMessages());
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('index')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        }
        return Redirect::to('index')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        $userdata = array( 
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
            Session::set('user', $userdata['username']);
            $username = $userdata['username'];
            $userID = $this->get_id_by_string('users', 'username', $username);
            Session::set('user_id', $userID);
            return 'Inloggad';
        } else {
            return 'Fel användarnamn eller lösenord.';
        }
    }
}
```

it always returns returns the string `Fel användarnamn eller lösenord.`

Comment: Just so you know, you're kinda doing auth in Laravel a bit wrong. What you have may possibly work, but you're doing a lot more work than you need to. First off don't worry about the session stuff - Laravel does this for you in the `Auth::attempt()` method - in subsequent requests you can use `Auth::check()` to see if the person is logged in or not, and `Auth::user()` to get the User model associated to the logged-in user. Secondly, you don't really need to validate the data before passing into `Auth::attempt()` - it kinda does its own validation anyway by checking for a user.

Comment: Lastly, you can use `Input::only(array('username', 'password'))` so get a keyed array from the input. Not a huge code saving, but makes the code kinda concise and clear. Personal preference I guess whether or not you use that one.

Comment: Also, the thing that complained about 30 days would be composer. Maybe you did a `composer update`, which would have updated your Laravel to the latest verison of the version specified in your `compser.json` file - there was a recentish breaking change introduced to 4.1 and 4.2 where you need to go in and add a few methods to your User model (and field to DB table). See [here](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26) for the official upgrade guide.